# How to add node above pgfplot Y axis max?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to add some nodes (labels) above the max value of the Y axis in a pgfplots. I came with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{TEST}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=Cost,ylabel=Gain]
      \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates { (10,100) (20,150) (40,225) (80,340) (160,510) (320,765) (640,1150) };
      \node at (axis cs:0,1200) [rotate=90, anchor=west] {Label 0};
      \node at (axis cs:200,1200) [rotate=90, anchor=west] {Label 200};
      \node at (axis cs:400,1200) [rotate=90, anchor=west] {Label 400};
      \node at (axis cs:600,1200) [rotate=90, anchor=west] {Label 600};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{TEST}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=Cost,ylabel=Gain, ymax=2000]
      \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates { (10,100) (20,150) (40,225) (80,340) (160,510) (320,765) (640,1150) };
      \node at (axis cs:0,1200) [rotate=90, anchor=west] {Label 0};
      \node at (axis cs:200,1200) [rotate=90, anchor=west] {Label 200};
      \node at (axis cs:400,1200) [rotate=90, anchor=west] {Label 400};
      \node at (axis cs:600,1200) [rotate=90, anchor=west] {Label 600};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In the first solution, the label are not visible. In the second they are visible, but I really want to "stop" the Y axis at 1200 and 2000. how could I get such a plot ? I guess that I should draw above the plot outside the `axis` environment, isn't it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `clip=false` to the `axis` options, by default anything drawn outside the axis limits are clipped away.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{TEST}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=Cost,ylabel=Gain,clip=false,ymin=0,ymax=1200]
      \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates { (10,100) (20,150) (40,225) (80,340) (160,510) (320,765) (640,1150) };
      \node at (axis cs:0,1200) [rotate=90, anchor=west] {Label 0};
      \node at (axis cs:200,1200) [rotate=90, anchor=west] {Label 200};
      \node at (axis cs:400,1200) [rotate=90, anchor=west] {Label 400};
      \node at (axis cs:600,1200) [rotate=90, anchor=west] {Label 600};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```